# Hive Table loaded from Spark dataframe performs poorly

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I created a Hive table with data stored as Parquet, snappy compressed.  It's an empty table to start with.  I loaded that table from Spark as shown-

```
hiveContext.read.parquet("/user/a_dgt_intel_trans_u/xpo/impression/event_dt=2017-01-30").registerTempTable("temp")
hiveContext.sql("select a.*,year(event_time)as year,month(event_time) as month,day(event_time)as dt from temp a").registerTempTable("temp1")
hiveContext.sql("insert into xpo_imp_ymd_hive partition(year,month,dt) select * from temp1")
```

When I did a select * from the table, I get this warning -

```
 WARNING: org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics: Ignoring statistics because created_by could not be parsed (see PARQUET-251): parquet-mr version 1.6.0
org.apache.parquet.VersionParser$VersionParseException: Could not parse created_by: parquet-mr version 1.6.0 using format: (.+) version ((.*) )?\(build ?(.*)\)
```

Doing a count(*) fails after a few seconds with this error msg -

```
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
]], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Container container_e82_1492612930020_0170_01_000054 finished with diagnostics set to [Container failed, exitCode=-104. Container [pid=40303,containerID=container_e82_1492612930020_0170_01_000054] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 7.9 GB of 6 GB physical memory used; 13.5 GB of 12.6 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_e82_1492612930020_0170_01_000054 :
```

Please let me know what I am missing

Comment: I don't see this issue when I create the hive table with 'stored as textfile' instead of 'stored as parquet'.  Also, I don't see the issue when the data is loaded into the parquet hive table from the text hive table.  I see the issue only when trying to load the parquet hive table directly from spark.

Comment: what version of spark and hive you are using?

Comment: SPARK 1.6 and HIVE 1.2